# Skimage Python33 Canny

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, python-3.3

Long story short, I'm just simply trying to get a canny edged image of `image.jpg`.

The documentation is very spotty so I'm getting very confused. If anyone can help that'd be greatly appreciated.

```
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
from skimage import data
from skimage import feature
from skimage import io


im=misc.imread('image1.jpg')
edges1 = feature.canny(im)
...
```

And I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array
```

Can anyone explain how to create a 2D array from an image file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect `image1.jpg` is a color image, so `im` is 3D, with shape (num_rows, num_cols, num_color_channels).  One option is to tell `imread` to flatten the image into a 2D array by giving it the argument `flatten=True`:

```
im = misc.imread('image1.jpg', flatten=True)
```

Or you could apply `canny` to just one of the color channels, e.g.

```
im = misc.imread('image1.jpg')
red_edges = feature.canny(im[:, :, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The canny edge detection needs a grayscale image input in order to work.
You can convert 3D (color) images to 2D (grayscale) using the rgb2gray module in scikit-image.

```
from skimage import io, features
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

image = rgb2gray(io.imread("image.png"))
edges = feature.canny(image)
```